# moments.js, 'type object' has no attribute 'utc'

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, flask

I am trying to use moments.js, but I have a lot of trouble with that. I am including moments as described in the mega tutorial

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-dates-and-times

meaning I use

```
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
moment = Moment()
moment.init_app(app)
```

now I have a function moment() available, which works in my case. However, if I want to display the time in UTC, I would like the appropriate option as explain in the docs

http://momentjs.com/docs/

which is moment.utc(). But that results in

'type object' has no attribute 'utc'

I am wondering what is the difference (if there is any) between the inclusion of mements I do and just including moments.js in the head?
I have a lot of trouble to get moment-timezone.js working and I think this is related to the issue I have with .utc().
any help is very much appreciated
thanks
carl

Comment: Its better to pass UTC time from server (Flask) and use moment.js in your javascript to convert UTC time to user's timezone. Normally we pass time in ISO format (`datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()`) from server

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_moment import Moment
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment()
moment.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    return render_template('main.html', now=datetime.utcnow())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

template - main.html

```
{% block page_content %}
{{ moment(now).format('LLL') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you are referring to is for JavaScript.

The code you are showing is written in Python. Either find the corresponding function in the Python wrapper to do the UTC conversion or call the .utc() function in JS inside of your view template.